# connect/disconnect bluetooth keyboard Adobe Air Android App Crash

Tags: android, apache-flex, bluetooth, air, stagewebview

My App crashes always after bluetooth keyboard connects or disconnects while StageWebView is active and the user is tapping on it.

I found out that Setting android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" on the main activity could solve this problem (works for native apps). But this is not supported by Adobe http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create Adobe Air Mobile Application
2. Use StageWebView to load and display an external Website
3. Run the Application on an Android Device
4. Connect bluetooth keyboard to your Device
5. Run the App
6. After the page has loaded select and deselect text on the page and connect/disconnect your keyboard a few times
7. The App will crash (unfortunately application has stopped)

The App does not crash if you destroy and reload StageWebView. But this is not an acceptable solution for my use case.

There is a related entry on Adobe bugbase:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4158541